# CSS Remove padding and apply full width to table columns from a class

Tags: html, css

I added the following CSS media query to a page, but can't figure out how to set the width of the upper column to full width,remove the padding of the lower column to center it, and center the button.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

/* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr, cuerpo_con { 
   display: inline-block;
   width:100%;
   position:relative;
   border-collapse:collapse;
   margin: 0 auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Off centered columns with different widths and padding

[image]

Here's the HTML
I see that the upper column has 400px width as well as the padding for the lower column set to 30px. Just can't figure out how to remove them with css so it all looks center on mobile devices.

```html
<div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom modulo_datos">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" style="width:400px;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><label>Cuenta:</label></td>
                    <td valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;"><span>3826</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:10px;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><label>Ruta:</label></td>
                    <td valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;"><span>1-11</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:10px;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><label>Dirección:</label></td>
                    <td valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;"><span>BO LEMPIRA OAK RIDGE</span></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td valign="top" style="padding-left:30px;">
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><label>Medidor:</label></td>
                    <td valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;"><span>20203948</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:10px;"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><label>Saldo:</label></td>
                    <td valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;"><span>LPS 0.00</span></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:20px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" colspan="2">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <button class="Pagos ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled" onclick="payNow( ['3826;0.00'] )" disabled="">
                      <span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-cart"></span>
                      <span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>Pagar Ahora
                    </button>
                  </td>
                  <td style="padding-left:30px;">
                      <button class="Info ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" onclick="abrirVentanaInfo('3826'); return False;">
                        <span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"></span>
                        <span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>Ver Información
                      </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your html as well? Maybe a snippet so that we can work on it and come up with solutions? `:)`

Comment: Code added, Thanks :)

Comment: Are you trying to apply styling changes on the HTML you have provided or have you also created the HTML code as well?

Comment: Can you add your full CSS reference?

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
  td {
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
    text-align: center;
  }
  table {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom modulo_datos">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top" style="width:400px;">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top"><label>Cuenta:</label></td>
                        <td valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;"><span>3826</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:10px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top"><label>Ruta:</label></td>
                        <td valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;"><span>1-11</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:10px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top"><label>Dirección:</label></td>
                        <td valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;"><span>BO LEMPIRA OAK RIDGE</span></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td valign="top" style="padding-left:30px;">
                  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td valign="top"><label>Medidor:</label></td>
                        <td valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;"><span>20203948</span></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:10px;"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td valign="top"><label>Saldo:</label></td>
                        <td valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;"><span>LPS 0.00</span></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:20px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top" colspan="2">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <button class="Pagos ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled" onclick="payNow( ['3826;0.00'] )" disabled="">
                          <span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-cart"></span>
                          <span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>Pagar Ahora
                        </button>
                      </td>
                      <td style="padding-left:30px;">
                          <button class="Info ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" onclick="abrirVentanaInfo('3826'); return False;">
                            <span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"></span>
                            <span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>Ver Información
                          </button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this code will help to solve the problems.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

table {
    width: 100%;
  }  
td {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: auto;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
}
tr {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom modulo_datos">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" style="width:400px;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><label>Cuenta:</label></td>
                    <td valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;"><span>3826</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:10px;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><label>Ruta:</label></td>
                    <td valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;"><span>1-11</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:10px;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><label>Dirección:</label></td>
                    <td valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;"><span>BO LEMPIRA OAK RIDGE</span></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td valign="top" style="padding-left:30px;">
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><label>Medidor:</label></td>
                    <td valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;"><span>20203948</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:10px;"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><label>Saldo:</label></td>
                    <td valign="top" style="padding-left:10px;"><span>LPS 0.00</span></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:20px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" colspan="2">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <button class="Pagos ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled" onclick="payNow( ['3826;0.00'] )" disabled="">
                      <span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-cart"></span>
                      <span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>Pagar Ahora
                    </button>
                  </td>
                  <td style="padding-left:30px;">
                      <button class="Info ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" onclick="abrirVentanaInfo('3826'); return False;">
                        <span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"></span>
                        <span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>Ver Información
                      </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```